# user/project names in CircleCI 1.1 API

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to get information from the Circle CI REST API.

I can get make any call that doesn't require a vcstype/username/project to work properly such as `/me?circle-token=<token>`, however I can't get any that require vcstype/username/project to return anything except a 404 error.

In particular:

- What is my username? Is it my github username (SuperTango)? I login to circleci with github, and the circleci "account settings" webpage doesn't actually show me any username. The `/me` API response has a field called `login` (which in my case is also "SuperTango"), but it doesn't have a field named `username`
- What is the actual project name I should use here? Is it the name of the github project?

When trying to get a list of builds for a particular project, I have the following:

- my username is "SuperTango"
- i'm a github user
- the project in github is called "funkware/funkware_app"

The docs say the url is:

`GET: /project/:vcs-type/:username/:project
Build summary for each of the last 30 builds for a single git repo.`

The base URL for all circleCI API requests is 
`https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/`

Here's what I'm trying for the URL:

`https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/SuperTango/funkware/funkware_app?circle-token=<token>`

This URL is not working for me. I get back a 404 response with the webpage.  As I mentioned up top, I can make the "/me" call, so I know my circle-token is correct.  I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already answered in the CircleCI Doc's [GitHub project](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/332). I'll answer again here for completeness.

---

1. **What is my username?** - This is the username for your repository on GitHub or Bitbucket. This could be a personal user account, or it can be an organization username.
2. **What is the actual project name?** - This is the repository name on GitHub or Bitbucket.

For the example provided, the API call would be: `https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/funkware/funkware_app?circle-token=<MY_TOKEN>`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm marking this as accepted.  The docs are a bit ambiguous, because your actual username isn't important in this case.This was where my confusion came from.  The username that the documents refer to when saying `:usename` is the the username that the project belongs to (again, possibly not your username as a user of github).

Comment: Working on improvements at the moment. :)